# Text leans more to one side than the other

Tags: html, css

As you can see from the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJwy9/) if you hover over the text there's more space between one side than the other, how can I resolve this.

The HTML for my problem is as follows:

```
<div id="mission"><a href="#">Our Mission</a></div>
```

THE CSS is as follows:

```
 #mission{
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display:inline-block;
  font: 800 1.313em "proxima-nova",sans-serif; 
  padding: 30px 30px;
  margin-top:150px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size:3.125em;
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 1.45em;
  position: scroll;
  background-color:black;
 }

#mission a{
color:#fff;
text-decoration: none;

 }

#mission a:hover{
color:;
text-decoration: none;
cursor:pointer;
background-color:green;
```

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour is mainly due to the fact that the specification (as far as I'm aware) is quite vague about the behaviour of text when using the letter-spacing property.  It's not entirely clear whether the property should only deal with spaces between letters, or whether the spacing is applied after each letter.

In this case, the spacing appears to be after each letter. By removing the letter-spacing property altogether, for example, you can see that there is no space following the last letter ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJwy9/2/))

```
#mission{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        display:inline-block;
      font: 800 1.313em "proxima-nova",sans-serif; 
      padding: 30px 30px;
      margin-top:150px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size:3.125em;
        text-align: center; 
        max-width: 606px;
        line-height: 1.45em;
        position: scroll;
        background-color:black;
}
```

To my knowledge there is no specific fix for this.  A hack around it may be to add a negative margin to the text to bring the edges in closer to the right hand side of the text.  Other than that it's a case of hoping that more controls for typography in webpages come in future CSS versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add left padding to the anchor tag.

```
#mission a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 0.15em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QJwy9/1/

Comment: That doesn't actually work, because the second line doesn't get the padding-left.